# Difference between .bind and other events

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between the following lines of code, or are they just 2 different ways to write the same thing:

```
$("p").click(function() { some code here });

$("p").bind("click", function(){ some other code here });
```

Am I over simplifying this? Because if you wanted to bind more than one event you could just chain the events, correct?

Comment: Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn

Comment: My question is worded better :) but yes I see the dupe now

Comment: This question is more general and easier to find so I don´t think it´s a duplicate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It also allows you to bind the same anonymous method to multiple events like:

```
$("p").bind("click dblclick mouseover mouseout", function(){ some other code here });
```

Answer (score 6):

Also note that binds allows for custom events

```
$(elem).bind('myEvent', function(){
   alert('myEvent!');
});
$(elem).trigger('myEvent'); //alerts 'myEvent!'
```

Answer (score 4):

The first version is just a shorthand for the second one.