# What is difference between $(".anything").click() and $(".anything").bind(click)

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between $(".anything").click() and $(".anything").bind(click)

```
$(".anything").click(function() {

});

$(".anything").bind('click', function() {

});
```

Comment: `.bind("click", ...)` should be a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first is a shortcut of the second. The second is actually wrong, `click` should have been quoted. Further, in the second you have the added benefit that you can bind the same function to multiple events, each separated by a space. E.g.

```
$(".anything").bind("click keypress blur", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 8):

Nothing, `click(function() { })` is just a shortcut for `bind("click", function() { })`.

From the jQuery docs:

> The jQuery library provides shortcut methods for binding the standard event types, such as .click() for .bind('click').

You can read more about `bind()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

Answer (score 4):

In that specific case, absolutely nothing.

However:

A) If you give `.click()` no argument, it triggers the event instead of setting the handler.

B) only `.bind()` lets you use the "namespaced" way of registering handlers:

```
$(whatever).bind('click.myEvent', function (e) { ... });
$(whatever).unbind('click.myEvent'); // Removes just that handler
```

Answer (score 2):

See this post, which points to the JQuery source to show that .click(fn) just calls .bind('click', fn): [jQuery: $().click(fn) vs. $().bind('click',fn);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn/518773#518773)

I usually only use the latter if:

- I want to bind multiple things, i.e. .bind('click focus', fn)
- Just to maintain convention if I call unbind later, i.e.:

> ```
> var fn = function() { alert('foo'); }
> $('#foo').bind('click', fn);
>
> ...
>
> $('#foo').unbind('click', fn);
> ```