# In JQuery when should you use .bind() over .click() - or any other given event?

Tags: jquery, bind, jquery-events

I understand the difference between Live and Bind but when should I use use `.bind()` over a 'standard' event method as shown below.

Are there any key differences in the way these two calls work?

```
$('.clickme').bind('click', function() {
  // Handler called.
});

$('.clickme').click(function() {
  // Handler called.
});
```

Comment: those are the same as far as implementation, just a shortcut

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They're effectively the same. However, using `bind()` allows you to make use of [namespaced events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events). This is [especially useful when writing plugins](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/09/namespace-your-events).

Comment: Ah very interesting. Will be looking into this more. Thanks @Shawn Chin

Answer (score 4):

in "bind" you can use multiple events

```
$('#foo').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('entered');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

They are the same. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn/518773#518773)

Comment: Yeah same! the question is When should we use it..? late but needed.

Answer (score 0):

I use the explicit methods when available. I use the bind when a method isn't available like for window.onbeforeunload

The other time to use bind is if your are developing and switching between "live" and "bind".

Answer (score 0):

use `.bind` when you want to bind to "event.namespace"

Actaully almost always use `.bind` and almost always use namespaces.

Comment: @Raynos--any special reason for this? what is the benefit of using only namespaces?

Comment: @codeninja `.unbind(".namespace")` the ability to unbind all events for a namespace on a node is gold.