# JavaScript On Browser Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 elements on a page, a title and content area for people to enter text.

The contents height is determined using JavaScript:

```
$('#body').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('#title').height() - 220);
```

Is there a way I can have it so when the window is resized, the #body changes its height?

Comment: Add a event on `window.resize`

Comment: Aha, I found it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's possible - just add the `resize` event handler like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#body').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('#title').height() - 220);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/bHQV5/2/)

Change re-size code as you want

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () { 
    $('#body').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('#title').height());
});
```

Comment: resize jfiddle output window

Comment: What's the different between using `.bind()` rather than `.resize()` like in the answer above? Does it do something different?

Comment: This two links will help you to understand http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865566/in-jquery-when-should-you-use-bind-over-click-or-any-other-given-event