# What is the difference between .bind('click') and .click() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

What is different between two below statement in jQuery:

**1) with `.bind`**

```
$("#username").bind('click',function(){
    //@todo
});
```

**2) without `.bind()`**

```
$("#username").click(function(){
    //@todo
});
```

So, when I need to use one of them?

Comment: The difference is 6 characters...

Comment: Duplicate: [jQuery: $().click(fn) vs. $().bind('click',fn);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn)

Comment: @patrick dw: I don't know it before. Sorry. Now I see.

Comment: @FelixKling That's a top 10 smart-ass comment, sir. Good work!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no difference. If you read the docs for [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) you will notice the following line:

> This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler)

You can confirm this by taking a quick look at the [jQuery source](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.click):

```
function (data, fn) {
    if (fn == null) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }
    //Notice the call to bind on the following line...
    return arguments.length > 0 ? this.bind(name, data, fn) : this.trigger(name);
}
```

I tend to use `.click` over `.bind`, simply because it's quicker to write. However, `.bind` can be used to attach the same listener to multiple events so it's useful in that case:

```
$("#something").bind("click mouseover", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

To expand upon the comment by @Tomalak, `.bind` is also useful when working with custom events. For pretty much any other event, there is a [shortcut method](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) just like `.click`. The jQuery source is as follows:

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error").split(" "), function( i, name ) {
    /*Call .bind for the respective event. There is a shortcut method 
    for each of the events listed above*/
});
```

Comment: Really? Love to your confirmation.

Comment: You can also write code that binds to custom events (or for dynamically selected ones) with `bind()`.

Comment: +1 for a nice thorough explanation and good references to both the jQuery documentation and the jQuery source code.

Answer (score 3):

There is not difference, `.click` is a shortcut for `.bind('click',`.

`.click()` called without argument is a shortcut for `.trigger('click'`.

Answer (score 2):

In this form there is no difference.  The `click` method is just a shortcut for `bind('click', ...)`.  Which to use is purely a matter of preference / style

Answer (score 0):

It is just a shortcut. There is really NO difference between them

> This method is a shortcut for .bind('click', handler) in the first two variations, and .trigger('click') in the third.

http://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

Using .click() the function is not triggered when touching an anchor using Safari browser in an iPhone with IOS 4x. It does with bind('click')