# Using .bind() vs simply calling the event

Tags: jquery

Please what is the difference between using jquery .bind() to attach an event to a selector and simply calling an event directly e.g .click() or .change()

Comment: So that you can bind multiple events to the same action I think

Comment: Already answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between

`$().click(fn)` or `$().change(fn)`

and

`$().bind('click',fn)` or `$().bind('change',fn)`

as in the background (jQuery source) the `click` and `change` methods use `bind`

Although as pointed out in this answer -> [jQuery: $().click(fn) vs. $().bind('click',fn);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn)

You can use bind for multiple events

Answer (score 1):

actually .click() .change() etc' are just a shorthand for using .bind()
with bind you could bind multiple events, custom events, etc