# What are the significant differences among $(sel).bind("click", $(sel).click(, $(sel).live("click", $(sel).on("click"?

Tags: jquery, onclick, click, bind, mouseclick-event

I've been using them for quite some time, but most of the time, I prefer the shorter one, however, I just want to really dig in to the nitty-gritty details. I may have been creating buggy codes and I don't want to contribute and spread lazily-done codes out in the web.

So, tell me:

> What are the significant advantages/disadvantages among them, or is it
>   just like ice cream, different flavors but same "feel-good" effect?

Everyone is encouraged to throw their expert opinions regarding this matter.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: $().click(fn) vs. $().bind('click',fn);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518762/jquery-clickfn-vs-bindclick-fn) (where the answers also discuss `on`)

Comment: The best answer is in docs for: [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @VisioN The docs are in fact too lengthy, so I posted the question to get pinpoint, accurate, distinct info from experts in the field.

Comment: @Thilo That particular question was asked in 2009. A lot had happened since then, so just to update mine and everyone else's technical info, I reposted a slightly the same, but different Q.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind()` was added in 1.0, `live()` in 1.3, `delegate()` in 1.4.2 and `on()` in 1.7.

As of 1.7 `on()` is the preferred use and `live()` is deprecated and not recommended at all.
If you are using 1.3 use `bind()` instead of `live()` and as of 1.4.2 use `delegate()` instead of `live()` and as of 1.7 use `on()` instead of any of the others.

Regarding `$("selector").click`. Taken from the `click()` [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/click/):

> In the first two variations, this method is a shortcut for
>   .bind("click", handler), as well as for .on("click", handler) as of
>   jQuery 1.7. In the third variation, when .click() is called without
>   arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click").

**Why use on() instead of the others?**
`on()` is the latest addition, joining the jQuery library in version 1.7. `on()` has several method signatures enabling it to deliver the same results previous version do but improved and optimised. To quote from the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers.

There is bascialy no need to use `bind()` or `delegate()` anymore. Sure it will work and there should be no harm in using those methods but I would always assume that the latest additions are optimised and improved on any of the drawbacks of previous versions (unless otherwise stated by the documentation as it is in the case of `live()`).
Based on that I would recommend to use `on()` instead.

The reason `live()` is not recommended full-stop is more to do with it's drawbacks. To quote from the `live()` [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live).

> Use of the .live() method is no longer recommended since later
>   versions of jQuery offer better methods that do not have its
>   drawbacks. In particular, the following issues arise with the use of
>   .live():
>
> - jQuery attempts to retrieve the elements specified by the selector
>     before calling the .live() method, which may be time-consuming on
>     large documents.
> - Chaining methods is not supported. For example, $("a").find(".offsite, .external").live( ... ); is not valid and does
>     not work as expected.
> - Since all .live() events are attached at the document element, events
>     take the longest and slowest possible path before they are handled.
> - On mobile iOS (iPhone, iPad and iPod Touch) the click event does not
>     bubble to the document body for most elements and cannot be used with
>     .live() without applying one of the following workarounds:
>
>   1. Use natively clickable elements such as a or button, as both of these
>        do bubble to document.
>   2. Use .on() or .delegate() attached to an element below the level of document.body, 
>        since mobile iOS does bubble within the body.
>   3. Apply the CSS style cursor:pointer to the element that needs to bubble
>        clicks (or a parent including document.documentElement). Note however,
>        this will disable copy\paste on the element and cause it to be
>        highlighted when touched.
> - Calling event.stopPropagation() in the event handler is ineffective in
>     stopping event handlers attached lower in the document; the event has
>     already propagated to document.
> - The .live() method interacts with other event methods in ways that can
>     be surprising, e.g., $(document).unbind("click") removes all click
>     handlers attached by any call to .live()!

There is a lot more goodies in the documentation though.

**Additional Resources**
[**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
[**bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind)
[**live() (don't use)**](http://api.jquery.com/live)
[**delegate()**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
[**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @DexterHuinda: You are more than welcome. Out of all the jQuery methods I found the multiple binding variations the most confusing at the start. But after sitting down and checking which release they were added I simply started always to use the latest. `live()` however seems to be the odd one out which I was always told to never use regardless of jQuery version.

Comment: Yeah well, I have never used `live()` and the name alone is confusing as to what particular purpose it really serves.

Comment: I did some more research and I don't think I was completly correct in explaining the issues with `live()`. It is more related to the way event bubbling works and how `live()` does this by default. I get more information on this and for completness of this post will edit it ones I got all the facts.

Comment: I updated my post to include the official facts on this now. Hope it helps.

Comment: Just fixed some additional version references I had mixed up, nothing major but wanted to make sure they are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in functionality in that particular case. However, `.on` is preferred over `.bind` as of jQuery 1.7, and as for `.click` - it's just a shorthand for a common event handler.

Comment: why is .on preferred over .bind? any significant reason?

Comment: @DexterHuinda: My guess is that, as it is the latest method for binding to be added to the jQuery library it is the most optimised at this time. Just a guess though.

Comment: @DexterHuinda: No clue. But I do find it looks better, personally =)