# HTML <select> JQuery .change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Alright I don't see why this isnt working. It seems pretty simple.

Here is my drop-down menu:

```
<div>
    <form>
        <select id='yearDropdown'>
            <c:forEach var="years" items="${parkYears}">
                <option value=/events.html?display_year=${years}<c:if test="${currentYear == years}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${years}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

and here is the JavaScript

```
$("#yearDropdown").change(function () {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Right now I just want to get it working so I can add functionality. Thanks!

Comment: What is the rendered output of the control(view source, inspect element, etc...)?

Comment: forgive me, I don't know what your asking. I'm a CS student. and I have practically no knowledge of javascript

Comment: Do you have it running in a $(document).ready(function(){ THIS CODE HERE });  or just a $(function(){ CODE HERE }); ?  Looks correct to me...

Comment: Rather than saying "it no work", could you tell us exactly what is happening? You get no alert, ok, got that. But does your console say anything? Have you loaded jQuery correctly? Is the context of this javascript event wireup inside of a `$(function(){ });` call?

Comment: using Xander's code worked. My console didn't say anything, just nothing happened when I selected an option in the drop down box

Comment: Why on earth is this so downvoted?  It's a perfectly reasonable and well formulated question.

Comment: Regarding the accepted answer, make sure you use `delegate` instead of `live` if you are using jQuery 1.6.x or earlier and `on()` instead of `live()` v1.7, due to the many drawbacks of `live()`. More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148053/448144

Answer (score 43, accepted):

That code is syntactically correct. Most likely running it at the wrong time.

You'll want to bind the event when the *DOM is ready*:

---

**Native JS/DOM**

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const yearDropDown = document.getElementById('yearDropdown');
    yearDropDown.addEventListener('change', () => { 
        alert(yearDropDown.value)
    });
});
```

---

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){ /* DOM ready */
    $("#yearDropdown").change(function() {
        alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Or, use `live`:

```
$("#yearDropdown").live('change', function() {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Or, use `delegate`:

```
$(document.body).delegate('#yearDropdown', 'change', function() {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Or, if you're using jQuery `1.7+`:

```
$("#yearDropdown").on('change', function() {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});
```

---

Nonetheless, it is usually best to execute script once the browser has finished rendering Markup.

Comment: It does not matter because `.change` will apply to every newly added element. (Correct me if it is incorrect)

Comment: @Derek:  You're wrong, it applies to elements that match the expression (#yearDropdown) the moment that line is executed.  jQuery doesn't monitor for new elements or anything alike.

Comment: @user1469925 The difference is that this function is called once the document has finished loading, and the DOM has been created.  Your code executes as soon as it's read, and the DOM might not be ready yet - the select doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @Hugo - But [it](http://api.jquery.com/live/) says use `.on` instead of `.live` because it is deprecated. And `.live` applies to every element that added after it is executed.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I guess I need to read up on the DOM. Like I said I'm a CS student doing an internship alittle bit over my head. Its fun though!

Comment: @Derek The reference to .live was added after my comment was made.  And yes, it should be .on; .live is deprecated.

Comment: @Hugo - The docs says it applies to every new element by doing this `$("body").on("change", "#yearDropdown", functionHere);`

Comment: As I said; that code snippet was added after I made my comment.

Comment: If you are using jQuery pre 1.7 do not use `live` but use `delegate` instead. Also, `live` was mainly useful for when you wanted to bind to dynamic injected elements. This is what `on()` is for now as `live` has a lot of drawbacks, See here for more details:http://stackoverflow.com/a/11148053/448144

Comment: I have the same problem, and for some reason, it is not working for me, either; /* the head of the HTML document is shared via a file called header.php, so I have no choice, but to do it in the body of the document. */
Here is my site: http://dinotator.biokdd.org/ResearchProject/tableViewer.php
/* I have nothing functional, but I am at least trying to get the table-selector functional, and have it control the title of the table as well as the table that loads */

Comment: For some weird reasons. All the above are not working. The change even did not trigger.

Comment: @MaXi32 I am having the same problem. I don't know why.

Comment: Non of the above working in the latest version, the answer must be updated accordingly

Answer (score 3):

I have tried your code [in jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/FGuVM/).
I manually added some years as options.
It works right.

Just bind the .change event in the $(document).ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#yearDropdown").change(function () {
      alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
  });​
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and is working for me, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/mobweb/2Skp9/

Are you sure jQuery has been loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help, but you could try this:

```
    $("#yearDropdown").live("change", function () {
    alert('The option with value ' + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. `

Comment: It is? Need to read up on release notes then I guess. Thanks for the info.