# JQuery Unbind and then bind

Tags: jquery, bind

I've found lots of examples on this topic.. however, I do not fully understand.  Does my logic seem correct?  I have a div as button (class of .myClass) and I don't want it clickable unless myCount >= 1.

```
// I want to unbind if myCount == 0
if ( myCount == 0) {
 $('.myClass').unbind().css("opacity","0.5");
} else {
 // **would this rebind?**
 $('.myClass').click(callMyFunction);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it 'rebind.' It's more like you're attaching another event handler. If it already has the event, clicking it would call the function twice.

Comment: you're right.  I'll change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use namespaced events, with `on()`. `bind()` has been deprecated.

```
var foo = function () { ... }

if (myCount)
  $('.myclass').on('click.foo', foo)
else
  $('.myclass').off('.foo')
```

Comment: Nice one. Just caution with `.foo` on the `off()`. I think that will unbind all events associated with the namespace. Might be better to use `$('.myclass').off('click.foo')` unless you want to unbind all off course.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but `.unbind()` removes all handlers attached to the element when called with no arguments. Therefore, `$('.myClass').unbind()` removes all event handlers attached to the elements with a class of `.myClass`. Since you only seem to be adding one event handler, `click`, it would be better to only unbind the `click` handler, like so: `$('.myClass').unbind('click')`. This way you won't be confused why other events are being unbinded if you add additional events later on.

Answer (score 2):

`click(callMyFunction)` is shorthand for `.bind("click", callMyFunction)` or `.on("click", callMyFunction)`.

To bind use `on()` to unbind use `off()`. Those are the preferred methods since jQuery 1.7. If you are using an older version use `bind()`, `unbind()`, or `delegate()` and `undelegate()`

```
$('.myClass').off('click')
```

and to bind

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function(){});
```

As mentioned in another post, using namespaces is an additional way to categorize your events such as `click.mynamespace` for example.

See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148053/448144) for much more detail on the different available binding methods and which were introduced when and have replaced what and why.

Some more resources:

- [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [**unbind()**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
- [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [**off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)