# cancel the function already trigger to execute

Tags: jquery

I have a function, there's 2 button after click pass different parameter and execute the same function, click button do ajax load html cover already loaded.

The problem is after I click `a`  then click `b` then I click `.reload_btn` it will execute twice.
Is it possible cancel the earlier click `a` execute function c?

```
$(".a").click(function(){
    function c(1);
});

$(".b").click(function(){
    function c(2);
});

function c(select_el){
    $('.reload_button').click(function(){
         .. // ajax reload content
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unbind the event before your click event. `$('.reload_button').unbind();`

Comment: like this?   $('.reload_button').unbind().click(function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Use `.on()` and `.off()` event handler.

```
$(".a").on('click',function(){
    function c(1);
});

$(".b").on('click',function(){
    function c(2);
});

function c(select_el){
    $('.reload_button').on('click',function(){
            $(document).off('click','.a');
         .. // ajax reload content
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! this works too but use on and off means when I do `off` should point which selector `on` click before?

Comment: @user1575921  Yes, but can also be used as a replacement of unbind()[depreciated]. instead use .on() and .off() attach/detach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Comment: @user1575921 I would like you to take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784257/jquery-unbind-and-then-bind

Answer (score 0):

Use have to use .abort() operation in your ajax call,

Follow this link [REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551175/how-to-cancel-abort-jquery-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this code :

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
    // Your ajax parameters
});

// Kill the ajax request
xhr.abort()
```

And have a look to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery) too.