# Is there a better way to attach events to AJAX loaded elements than to use .live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the newer jQuery `.click()`, `.submit()`, etc. was replaced by:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    //
});
```

in terms of best practice. Did anything similar happen to `.live()`? Or is this still the best way to do it?

```
$('#foo').live('click', function() {
    //
});
```

Comment: See [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) && [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: Didn't `on` replace `live` as well?

Comment: Voting to close, since this is easily answered by reading the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live)

Comment: @Blazemonger: If you believe this question does not show any research effort than that is what the downvote feature is for, according to it's tool-tip anyway. Lack of research is not a good reason to close question in my opinion or we would be closing nearly all basic questions. I'm sure though that several duplicates can be found of this question and that would be a valid reason for closing a question. The current 2 votes on closing for reasons of the question being to localized is not the correct reason though, nor is lack of research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**On()**](http://api.jquery.com/on) has all the abilities of all other bindings. To bind to dynamic elements you can use `on()` like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function() {
    //
});
```

Preferably you want to use a close static element instead of `document`.

To quote from another post of mine regarding the many binding methods jQuery has on offer:

> `bind()` was added in 1.0, `live()` in 1.3, `delegate()` in 1.4.2 and
>   `on()` in 1.7.
>
> As of 1.7 `on()` is the preferred use and `live()` is deprecated and
>   not recommended at all. If you are using 1.3 use `bind()` instead of
>   `live()` and as of 1.4.2 use `delegate()` instead of `live()` and as of
>   1.7 use `on()` instead of any of the others.

You can see the full post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11148053/448144), which also list the many drawbacks of `live()` and why it should not be used any more in jQuery 1.7 or later.

Answer (score 3):

Delegation using `.on()` is the correct way instead of using live

```
$('staticAncestorElement').on('click','#foo',function(){

});
```

as you can see from the jQuery [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) documents

> $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
>
> $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
>
> $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+

Comment: `staticAncestorElement`, rather, since it's not required to be a direct parent.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas True as Parent can be taken the wrong way - changing it

Answer (score 1):

> With the newer jQuery .click(), .submit(), etc. was replaced by

They weren't replaced. `click` and `submit` still work but now they are shortcuts to `on`. The methods that are deprecated are `bind` and `live`. Now you can do this to delegate events:

```
$(closestStaticParent).on('click', 'element', function(){ ... })
```

Answer (score 1):

`.click` was not replaced with `.on("click"`. Read the documentation.

`As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.`

`.live` was replaced by `.on` and `.off`.

Other functions like `.click` will continue to work as expected

- [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) (newer version of [.die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/))

Comment: If you got `off`, you might as well list [die](http://api.jquery.com/die/) for completness :)